# Error when building Pecl extension

Tags: php, build, makefile, pecl

I am trying to build the SCA_SDO extension but when I run the `make` command I am getting the following error:

```
make
/bin/sh /home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/libtool --mode=compile g++ -I/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4 -I. -I/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/include -I/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/main -I/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/libxml2  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp -o sdo.lo 
libtool: compile:  g++ -I/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4 -I. -I/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/include -I/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/main -I/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/sdo.o
In file included from /home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:42:0:
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/php_sdo_int.h:128:20: error: 'function_entry' does not name a type
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:80:8: error: conflicting specifiers in declaration of 'arginfo_sdo_dataobject'
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:86:8: error: conflicting specifiers in declaration of 'arginfo___get'
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:90:8: error: conflicting specifiers in declaration of 'arginfo___set'
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:95:1: error: 'function_entry' does not name a type
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:103:8: error: conflicting specifiers in declaration of 'arginfo_sdo_dataobject_createdataobject'
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:107:1: error: 'function_entry' does not name a type
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:119:8: error: conflicting specifiers in declaration of 'arginfo_sdo_sequence_getproperty'
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:123:8: error: conflicting specifiers in declaration of 'arginfo_sdo_sequence_move'
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:128:8: error: conflicting specifiers in declaration of 'arginfo_sdo_sequence_insert'
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:134:1: error: 'function_entry' does not name a type
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:144:8: error: conflicting specifiers in declaration of 'arginfo_sdo_list_insert'
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:149:1: error: 'function_entry' does not name a type
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:158:8: error: conflicting specifiers in declaration of 'arginfo_sdo_datafactory_create'
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:163:1: error: 'function_entry' does not name a type
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:170:1: error: 'function_entry' does not name a type
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:177:8: error: conflicting specifiers in declaration of 'arginfo_sdo_das_datafactory_addType'
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:183:8: error: conflicting specifiers in declaration of 'arginfo_sdo_das_datafactory_addPropertyToType'
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:192:1: error: 'function_entry' does not name a type
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:201:1: error: 'function_entry' does not name a type
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:214:1: error: 'function_entry' does not name a type
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:225:1: error: 'function_entry' does not name a type
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:234:1: error: 'function_entry' does not name a type
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:253:1: error: 'function_entry' does not name a type
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:263:8: error: conflicting specifiers in declaration of 'arginfo_sdo_model_type_identifier'
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:267:1: error: 'function_entry' does not name a type
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:281:1: error: 'function_entry' does not name a type
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:298:1: error: 'function_entry' does not name a type
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:310:1: error: 'function_entry' does not name a type
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:325:8: error: conflicting specifiers in declaration of 'arginfo_sdo_model_reflectiondataobject_export'
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:330:1: error: 'function_entry' does not name a type
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:352:1: error: 'function_entry' does not name a type
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:359:1: error: 'function_entry' does not name a type
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:373:13: error: 'function_entry' does not name a type
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp: In function 'int zm_startup_sdo(int, int)':
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:447:2: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:450:2: error: 'sdo_propertyaccess_methods' was not declared in this scope
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:454:2: error: 'sdo_dataobject_methods' was not declared in this scope
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:460:2: error: 'sdo_sequence_methods' was not declared in this scope
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:465:2: error: 'sdo_list_methods' was not declared in this scope
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:469:2: error: 'sdo_list_methods' was not declared in this scope
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:473:2: error: 'sdo_list_methods' was not declared in this scope
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:477:2: error: 'sdo_datafactory_methods' was not declared in this scope
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:481:2: error: 'sdo_das_dataobject_methods' was not declared in this scope
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:486:2: error: 'sdo_das_datafactory_methods' was not declared in this scope
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:491:2: error: 'sdo_das_changesummary_methods' was not declared in this scope
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:495:2: error: 'sdo_das_setting_methods' was not declared in this scope
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:499:2: error: 'sdo_list_methods' was not declared in this scope
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:503:2: error: 'sdo_model_type_methods' was not declared in this scope
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:507:2: error: 'sdo_model_property_methods' was not declared in this scope
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:511:5: error: 'sdo_das_df_methods' was not declared in this scope
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:515:5: error: 'sdo_dataobjectimpl_methods' was not declared in this scope
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:519:5: error: 'sdo_sequenceimpl_methods' was not declared in this scope
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:523:5: error: 'sdo_model_typeimpl_methods' was not declared in this scope
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:527:5: error: 'sdo_model_propertyimpl_methods' was not declared in this scope
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:531:5: error: 'sdo_model_reflectiondataobject_methods' was not declared in this scope
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:535:5: error: 'sdo_exception_methods' was not declared in this scope
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:539:5: error: 'sdo_exception_methods' was not declared in this scope
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:544:5: error: 'sdo_exception_methods' was not declared in this scope
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:549:5: error: 'sdo_exception_methods' was not declared in this scope
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:554:5: error: 'sdo_exception_methods' was not declared in this scope
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:559:5: error: 'sdo_exception_methods' was not declared in this scope
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:564:5: error: 'sdo_exception_methods' was not declared in this scope
/home/Alison/Downloads/SCA_SDO-1.2.4/sdo.cpp:569:5: error: 'sdo_cppexception_methods' was not declared in this scope
make: *** [sdo.lo] Error 1
```

Seems I'm not the only one:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=58951

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having this same issue right now and just cannot find a way to fix it other than hacking the build files.

I am using CentOS 6.3, PHP5.3 and trying to do some testing for a UPS Quantum View project.

It seems to me like this issue has never really been resolved as I find references to it all over.

I guess the only solution I have found to far is to not use the extension at all and instead use a more generic XML builder.

If I come across anything useful I will update here.

[EDIT] OK, I just came across this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phpsoa/HQVxiBmsFv0

Comment: Thanks for that! Will give it a go tomorrow and report back on how it goes.

Comment: I can get it to build fine, but I'm unable to load the extension due to an error stating that it's a wrong ELF class. How would I compile it for 32 bit?

Comment: What system are you compiling it on?

Comment: take a look in your /usr/lib folder and make sure there are no symlinks that point to /usr/lib64

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue trying to build something else, and it turned out to be that I was using a modified version of one of the relevant header files. Check to see if the program you're building specifies a particular version or source of the headers needed (perhaps in a README), and try to get fresh copies of precisely the file specified and make sure that they are the ones used at build time (often just copying them into the root directory of the source tree should do it).